# riff chunk - utility class for working with RIFF chunks

Tags: c++, c++17

For a personal project (reading media file metadata) I created a small/fast utility class for working with RIFF chunks.

Support:

- defining chunks by 32 bit integral value
- defining chunks using 4 ASCII characters
- splitting chunks into 2 16 bit integral values (useful for parsing RIFF headers)
- comparing chunks for equality

Not supported (could be added but I didn't need it for a windows-only home project):

- endian-ness changes

header file:

```
#include <array>
#include <cstdint>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>

namespace wpcs::riff
{
    /// @brief chunk of data (as specified by RIFF format)
    ///
    /// @see http://soundfile.sapp.org/doc/WaveFormat/
    class chunk final
    {
        std::array<std::byte, 4> data_;

    public:
        explicit chunk(std::uint32_t data = {});

        std::string string() const;
        std::uint32_t uint32() const;
        std::array<std::uint16_t, 2> uint16s() const;

        inline bool operator==(chunk const &x) const
        {
            return data_ == x.data_;
        }

        inline bool operator!=(chunk const &x) const
        {
            return data_ != x.data_;
        }
    };

    inline namespace literals
    {
        inline auto operator""_chunk(char const *const str, std::size_t size)
        {
            if (size != 4)
            {
                std::string msg{"Bad chunk: "};
                std::copy(str, str + size, msg.end());
                throw std::logic_error{msg};
            }
            auto value = std::uint32_t{};
            std::copy(str, str + size, reinterpret_cast<char *>(&value));
            return chunk{value};
        }

        inline auto operator""_chunk(unsigned long long x)
        {
            return chunk{static_cast<std::uint32_t>(x)};
        }
    } // namespace literals

} // namespace wpcs::riff
```

implementation file:

```
#include <riff/chunk.hpp>

namespace wpcs::riff
{
    chunk::chunk(std::uint32_t data)
        : data_{}
    {
        auto start = reinterpret_cast<std::byte *>(&data);
        auto stop = start + sizeof(data);
        std::copy(start, stop, begin(data_));
    }

    std::uint32_t chunk::uint32() const
    {
        return *reinterpret_cast<std::uint32_t const *const>(&data_[0]);
    }

    std::string chunk::string() const
    {
        constexpr auto const zero = std::byte{0};
        constexpr auto const null_char = '.';

        auto result = std::string(4, null_char);
        std::transform(begin(data_), end(data_), begin(result), [&](std::byte b) {
            if (b == zero)
                return null_char;
            return static_cast<char>(b);
        });
        return result;
    }

    std::array<std::uint16_t, 2> chunk::uint16s() const
    {
        auto result = std::array<std::uint16_t, 2>{};

        result[0] = static_cast<std::uint8_t>(data_[1]);
        result[0] <<= 8;
        result[0] += static_cast<std::uint8_t>(data_[0]);

        result[1] = static_cast<std::uint8_t>(data_[3]);
        result[1] <<= 8;
        result[1] += static_cast<std::uint8_t>(data_[2]);

        return result;
    }

} // namespace wpcs::riff
```

usage (tests written using catch2):

```
#define CATCH_CONFIG_MAIN
#include <catch2/catch.hpp>

#include <riff/chunk.hpp>

TEST_CASE("wpcs::riff::chunk", "[chunk]")
{
    GIVEN("an empty chunk")
    {
        auto const c = wpcs::riff::chunk{};

        WHEN("a string representation is created")
        {
            THEN("the string is filled with dots (representing null clars)")
            {
                REQUIRE(c.string() == "....");
            }
        }

        WHEN("a unit32 representation is created")
        {
            THEN("the representation is filled with zeros")
            {
                auto const value = c.uint32();
                REQUIRE(value == std::uint32_t{});
            }
        }

        WHEN("a uint16 representation is created")
        {
            THEN("the representation contains two zeros")
            {
                auto const values = c.uint16s();
                REQUIRE(values.size() == 2);
                REQUIRE(values[0] == std::uint16_t{});
                REQUIRE(values[1] == std::uint16_t{});
            }
        }
    }

    GIVEN("a user defined string literal representation of a chunk")
    {
        using namespace wpcs::riff::literals;

        auto const c = "WAVE"_chunk;

        THEN("it's representations are correct")
        {
            REQUIRE(c.uint32() == 0x45564157);
            REQUIRE(c.string() == "WAVE");

            auto const short_ints = c.uint16s();
            REQUIRE(short_ints[0] == 0x4157);
            REQUIRE(short_ints[1] == 0x4556);
        }
    }

    GIVEN("a user defined numeric literal representation of a chunk")
    {
        using namespace wpcs::riff::literals;

        auto const c = 1163280727_chunk;

        THEN("it's representations are correct")
        {
            REQUIRE(c.uint32() == 1163280727);
            REQUIRE(c.string() == "WAVE");

            auto const short_ints = c.uint16s();
            REQUIRE(short_ints[0] == 0x4157);
            REQUIRE(short_ints[1] == 0x4556);
        }
    }
}
```

Please review for possible code improvements and code style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## This does not represent RIFF chunks

A RIFF chunk is more than just the 4 byte identifier. A chunk consists of a header, data and padding bytes. Furthermore, the header contains the identifier as well as the size of the data.

## Is the identifier an `uin32_t` or an array of 4 `std::byte`s?

It is a bit weird to store the identifier internally as a `std::array<std::byte, 4>`, but none of the public member functions use that format. A lot of the code is unnecessarily complex just because you have to convert to and from that format.

I would either just store it as a `uint32_t` internally, to match what you pass into the constructor, or alternatively, since a RIFF chunk identifier consists of 4 ASCII characters, I would just define it as `char id[4]`.

## Unnecessary use of user-defined literals

Instead of declaring user-defined literals, I would just overload the constructor to take a C string as an argument. This way, instead of `"WAVE"_chunk`, you can write `chunk("WAVE")`, which is about the same length, and much less surprising.

## Unaligned access

You are using type punning to convert `std::array<std::byte, 4>` to `uint32_t`, but there is no guarantee that `std::array<std::byte, 4>` has the same alignment as `uint32_t`. While a `chunk` declared on the stack might be properly aligned in practice, it is not that hard to have a situation where a `chunk` is not aligned as you expect. Consider for example:

```
struct foo {
    char x;
    wcps::riff::chunk chunk;
};
```

You will find that `sizeof(struct foo)` is 5, and `offsetoff(struct foo, chunk)` is 1.
Converting to `uint32_t` using type-punning is undefined behavior, and might crash on platforms that do not support unaligned loads and stores.

## Writing out of bounds

In this code:

```
std::string msg{"Bad chunk: "};
std::copy(str, str + size, msg.end());
throw std::logic_error{msg};
```

You are explicitly copying `str` to after the end of `msg`. This is a buffer overflow. Instead, I would just write:

```
throw std::logic_error(std::string("Bad chunk: ") + str::string(str, size));
```